# Error with kSOAP2

Tags: android, web-services, wsdl, ksoap2

I am trying to submit a username and the device ID of the phone to my Server but I keep getting following error:

> W/System.err﹕ SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://eventmanagement.management.de/", local:"username"). Expected elements are <{}deviceID>,<{}username> ' faultactor: 'null' detail: null

This is my code:

```
       PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
       pi.setNamespace(NAMESPACE);
       pi.setName("username");
       pi.setValue(userName.getText().toString());
       pi.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
       request.addProperty(pi); 
       pi.setNamespace(NAMESPACE);
       pi.setName("deviceID");

       pi.setValue(android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(
       getContentResolver(), 
       android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID));
       pi.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
       request.addProperty(pi);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = 
         new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
```

This is the wsdl file:

```
 <xs:complexType name="addUser">
   <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="username" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="deviceID" type="xs:string"/>
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Can somebody help me pls? 
I have searched for 2 hours and found nothing.

Edit2:
Top-left corner the http-Request dump 
Right corner the SoapUI generated request which works
http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4013/5iwbvowk_png.htm

Comment: Is there a reason why I can't put a greeting in my question ?:D

Comment: Try using `String.class` instead of `PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS`

Comment: Tried that before. Didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried simply adding property using below flavor of `addProperty`

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
request.addProperty("username", username);
request.addProperty("deviceID", deviceID);
```

Also, you can make sure that you have a valid value and you are not hitting any `NPE` while accessing `userName.getText().toString()`

Comment: yip. Tried that one, too. No change.

Comment: Have you tried to make `request/response` using SoapUI and confirm that there is no issue with your `web service` or `wsdl`?

Comment: For better debugging, try setting `androidHttpTransport.debug = true` before making transport call `androidHttpTransport.call(...)` . You should be able to see `request` and `response` dumps. See if your request is correct in accordance with what you can see in your `SoapUI` (or you already have a clear picture )

Comment: http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4013/5iwbvowk_png.htm

In the Top-left corner there is the request dump and in the left corner that is the SoapUi Request. But I don't know exaktly what I have to change

Comment: could you please provide me screenshot for request dump, with changes in my answer, where you won't explicitly mention name spaces or type for properties

Comment: That is the request dump with the changes you mentioned: http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4013/vsi6zlij_png.htm

Comment: Ok, it worked with a combination.

First of all the changes you told me to do. 
Then I removed the dotNet-Flag.
And then- again thanks for mentioning SoapUI- I recognized that SoapUI could create a User with the request dump but my Client coudn't. 

It was an error within the Server. The developer made a mistake. Thanks

Comment: Great!! Ya SoapUI is a nice to have tool for us :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should remember to declare your property as new after u add the first one.

> pi = new PropertyInfo();

```
   PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
   pi.setNamespace(NAMESPACE);
   pi.setName("username");
   pi.setValue(userName.getText().toString());
   pi.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
   request.addProperty(pi); 

   // here
   pi = new PropertyInfo();  
   pi.setNamespace(NAMESPACE);
   pi.setName("deviceID");
   pi.setValue(android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(
   getContentResolver(), 
   android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID));
   pi.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
   request.addProperty(pi);
```

and one more thing, remember to call your androidHttpTransport

```
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope,null);
SoapPrimitive respond = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
```

UPDATED:
Is your request pass in exact parameter you want to? When debugging, you can see the webservice name along with value name and parameter you pass in.

> ConnectionString{username=manager; password=password123; }

Comment: Yea sorry, I do call the androidHttpTransport. That's the line where the error occurs.

Tried your code. Sadly it didn't work.

Comment: How about the parameter you pass in? I saw your error mention expected element device ID come before username.

Comment: Now it changed to: 

SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://eventmanagement.management.de/", local:"deviceID"). Expected elements are <{}deviceID>,<{}username> ' faultactor: 'null' detail: null

Comment: Had you debug and check is both that parameter pass into your request successfully?

Comment: Yes. Debugging told me everythings fine until call of androidHttpTransport

Comment: added a picture in original post